# How to get size of array inside an json object

Tags: javascript, html, json

this is my json object

[image: json]

I need to get length of itemDetails array object, 
I'm using

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[0].itemDetails.length; i++) {
                itmCode = "it001";
                itmName = "soap";
                Qty = "4";
                //netAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Net_Amt).toFixed(2);
                //paidAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Paid_Amt).toFixed(2);
                //balance = (parseFloat(netAmt) - parseFloat(paidAmt)).toFixed(2); //id = "damt['+i+']"
                $("#invoiceDetailTbl tbody").append("<tr id=" + i + ">" + "<td>" + itmCode + "</td>" + "<td>" + itmName + "</td>" + "<td>" + Qty + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                noOfItems = parseInt(noOfItems) + parseInt(Qty);
                noOfProducts = parseInt(noOfProducts) + 1;
            }
```

but always get 0 as length

Comment: There's no arrays within the JSON object, just a couple of methods.

Comment: *"this is my json object"* No it isn't. It's just an object. JSON is a *textual* notation.

Comment: `data[0].itemDetails.length` is correct for what you've shown. If it's not working, there's a problem in where and how the code you've shown is getting called (perhaps a timing issue?).

Comment: could you please post your code and `JSON` you are getting? and do you call `JSON.parse(data)` before accessing its' fields?

Comment: jason is in my image and code is also there

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana Did you get your solution? Perhaps `@Crowder` is correct. The code is fine, it must be an issue where you are using. Try `console.log(data[0].itemDetails)` before the `for` loop and check what data you are getting.